# Can I give headernames to columns in a structure field?

Tags: matlab, structure, field, names

I have a structure with multiple fields and these fields have multiple columns. I would like to give the columns of these fields names instead of 1,2,3... I am not going to reference to the columns by their names but just for clarity. For instance:

structure.field1 consists of 3 columns of data and I would like to name these for instance columns:

1 = Time

2 = Place

3 = Date

How can I do this without the use of tables but sticking with the structure!!

Comment: Why not use `tables`? They are exactly what you are describing. Otherwise would it not make the most sense to just have 3 subfields per field? So `structure.field1.Time` and `structure.field1.Place`?

Comment: @Dan I need the nesting because I am dealing with 10 airports that all contain 2 different fields. Field 1 consisting of three columns time, place, date and field 2 consisting of three other columns. I do not wish to have 10 different tables but a nesting structure: 


    `structure.airportname.field1` and
    `structure.airportname.field2`


and then instead of three subfields for field1 and field2 each, I would like to have the three columns of data next to eachother with header names for a clear representation. Can this be done?

Comment: What about a `table` inside a `struct`...?

Comment: THANKS guys, problems solved. I went with @Dev-iL idea!

Comment: @Paul I still don't understand why you don't use a `table`, just put the `table` in the `struct`. However if you are using `struct`s then it makes more sense to just use sub fields.

Comment: MATLAB is good for working with matrices. If you’re only going to have single values each with its own tag, or tabular data, it seems like a proper SQL database would be a lot more appropriate. Look into SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by implementing a table inside the structure. Thanks @Dev-iL for the suggestion